# Запуск консольной команды из Java-кода

Tags: java

У меня стоит задача запустить из Java-кода вот такую команду:

```
winpty docker exec -it apache-mbk-corp php html/lara/artisan log:save '{...}'
```

Как это сделать? Не смог сообразить, как правильно это сделать с помощью класса `Runtime`. Пробовал написать скрипт, но тоже не сообразил как его вызвать из Java-кода.

Скрипт (script.sh):

```
#!C:/Program Files/Git/git-bash.exe
winpty docker exec -it apache-mbk-corp php html/lara/artisan log:save '{...}'
```

Пробовал вот так:

```java
String s2 = "D:\\CORP\\auto_test\\src\\test\\java\\script.sh";
try
{
    System.out.println("start");
    String cmd[] = {"bash", s2};
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    proc.waitFor();
    proc.destroy();
    System.out.println("success");
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

При выполнении кода из контейнера с джава приложением:

```
 try
        {
            System.out.println("start");
            String[] command = {"bash", "pwd"};
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            System.out.write(proc.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
            System.out.write(proc.getErrorStream().readAllBytes());
//            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./tests/script.sh");
            int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exit code is " + exitCode);
            proc.destroy();
            System.out.println("success");
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------");
        try
        {
            System.out.println("start");
            String[] command = {"bash", "script_linux.sh"};
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            System.out.write(proc.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
            System.out.write(proc.getErrorStream().readAllBytes());
//            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./tests/script.sh");
            int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exit code is " + exitCode);
            proc.destroy();
            System.out.println("success");
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Выдает:
На первый -
/bin/pwd: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file
Exit code is 126
На второй -
bash: script_linux.sh: No such file or directory
Exit code is 127

Comment: А какой результат? Есть ли ошибки при выполнении этого кода? Если есть, то добавьте текст ошибки и стектрейс в вопрос.

Comment: А нет ошибки как таковой. Команда выполняется а результата нет. Я вот создал sh скрипт с одержимым как сверху. При запуске его вручную через idea результат есть. А если запустить через Runtime.geteRuntime.exec() то ошибок нет, скрипт отрабатывает , но и результата тоже нет. Чт овполне логично. Значит как-то неправильно синтаксически использую

Comment: Как велик текст, который печатает скрипт? 10 строк? 1000? 1000000?

Comment: Он не печатает а сохраняет строку в базу данных. НУ не знаю 300 симвлоов? 400?

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, вы хотите запустить команду `bash script.sh`:

```java
String[] command = {"bash", "script.sh"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Чтобы вывести результат работы этой команды, воспользуйтесь методами [`getInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) и [`getErrorStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--):

```java
process.getInputStream().transferTo(System.out);
process.getErrorStream().transferTo(System.out);
```

*(Метод [`transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) доступен только с Java 9 и выше, для остальных версий Java используйте [другие способы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43157) для работы с потоками данных)*

Кроме этого, по окончанию работы скрипта распечатайте код возврата:

```java
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exit code is " + exitCode);
```

Это даст вам больше информации о том, какие ошибки возникли при запуске скрипта.

Comment: Выдает: На первый - /bin/pwd: /bin/pwd: cannot execute binary file Exit code is 126 На второй - bash: script_linux.sh: No such file or directory Exit code is 127

Answer (score 0):

Может кому то пригодится. По итогу я в рантайме создавал внутри php контейнера файл exec.php, который принимал на вход в качестве аргумента команду определенную в php контейнере и вызывал ее выполнение через файл artisan